# Get file extension from file name string

Tags: flutter, file, dart

I was trying to get file extension with dart code as this,

```
var url = downloadUrl.toString();
String fileExtension = '';
String fileName = path.split("\/").last;
bool fileExt = false;
for (var characterUrl = 0;
     characterUrl < fileName.length;
     characterUrl++) {
     if (String.fromCharCode(fileName.codeUnitAt(characterUrl)) == '.' && !fileExt) {
      fileExt = true;
     }
     if (fileExt) {
          fileExtension += String.fromCharCode(fileName.codeUnitAt(characterUrl));
     }
}
```

When having a file named as:

> eg: *Screenshot_2021-06-10_co.com.app.jpg*

It returns me:

> ".com.app.jpg"

But I would like just to get the *.jpg*

In other file names it works perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

You're overthinking this solution here. Just use methods already made for you in the [`String`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/String-class.html) class. Since you already have the file name, you can find the last instance of the `.` character with the preexisting [`lastIndexOf`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/String/lastIndexOf.html) method and get the substring with that index:

```dart
String fileName = 'Screenshot_2021-06-10_co.com.app.jpg';
String fileExt = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('.'));
```